# Create a workflow for slack bot?

Tags: slack

I want to sent a recurring message to a bot every day but as I can see there is only option for slack channels. Is there any option to do that ? (without adding new apps, because I am not an admin user.)

Answer (score 0):

Answer from slack team ;

> I'm afraid it's not currently possible to send a message to a bot user
> or an app, you can only send it to a person or a channel. I also
> explored other functionalities, like our `/reminder` option, but
> unfortunately it also is not able to send a recurring message to a bot
> .
>
> However, we do provide more customization if you and/or your team can
> create a Slack API app. If you do that, it will allow you to send the
> message to the original bot. If you want to take that route, you can
> get more information on this page: https://api.slack.com/.